# Java EE Mobile Website

Tags: java, html

Is it possible to make a Mobile website i.e. with like jsp or servlets which uses java to connect to a Java SE Application Server using RMI or something like that?

It needs to have login as I would log in to an applet (which is already up an running and works) which connects to the Application Server and 'talks' to the server.

Now what I want is that I have to be able to use a mobile device i.e. sumsung tablet or blackberry to view a mobile website, log in with the same details as per the applet, and be able to do some of the same stuff that I will be able to do in an applet.

Is this possible? And what would i use?

Comment: Mobile website doesn't really differ from non-mobile websites. The main difference in page layouts optimized for small screens. So yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Everything works the exact same way, because while using JSP you will get an ordinary HTML page at client site.

All you have to do is optimize your layout so it looks good on a small screen.

Comment: Thanks! Then my training starts today! lol, okay so what would be the best to use? jsp? Servlet? I haven't done any web dev with java since I began, so I still want to learn either jsp or servlets or something which I will need to use for the mobile website.

Comment: You will need to use both JSP and Servlet to do web development in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile phone is capable just like a normal linux/windows desktop. All programming constructs will work. You can also start a client socket with a java server somewhere in the internet.

Do this, create a ec2 ubuntu server, open up port 23123 using the security group, write a piece of java server socket code, wait for a read on objectiostream string object.

On your android client, open a socket that connects to this servers ec2 dns name on port 23123, and send the string object using objectiostream.

It worked for me, it will for you :)